# Elasticsearch Optimising Storage

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Using Elasticsearch v 6.2. I've just started looking at an index that's almost become unmanageable (and with obsolete fields) in terms of storage and see any possible ways to optimise it. When I looked at the mapping, it has around 200 fields with quite a bit of analysis applied. As a first step, I'd like to see which fields are occupying more space or in other words which field has more terms? I'd then produce a report to the business to see if this field is actually required or not. Is this stats possible to get in ES? Or any other pointers are welcome.